# Calculating Distance Using node:(x,y)

Tags: python, nodes, distance, networkx

I'm very, very new to Python and need help calculating euclidean distances between the origin and all of the nodes in my graph.

Specifically, I can't figure out how to call the x and y coordinates from my data to use them in the distance equation. I'm using node:(x,y) to add nodes with positions.

A simple example of my problem is below.

```
    import networkx as nx
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import math

    g = nx.Graph()
    pos={
    1:(0,0),
    2:(5,5),
    3:(10,10)}
    g.add_nodes_from(pos)
    nx.draw(g,pos,with_labels=True)
    plt.show()
```

This draws the points where I want them.
The following part is where I can't figure out how to pull my coordinates for use in an equation.

```
    distances={}
    origin = g.node(1)
    for node in g.nodes():
        distance[node]=round(math.sqrt(((origin[x]-node[x])**2)+ 
        ((origin[y]-node[y])**2)),2)
```

I'm aware that "origin[x]-node[x]" is totally wrong, I'm just saying I want x from my node:(x,y) data structure.

Thank you! I know this is probably a simple question but I really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

`x` is just the first value in the tuple, in your case `x = pos[node][0]`.
However, it is often more expressive and elegant to "unpack" such variables:

```
x, y = pos[node]
```

I would rewrite your code bit like so:

```
distances = dict() # should probably be an array, but hey, its your code
origin = 1
(x0, y0) = pos[origin]
for node, (x1, y1) in pos.items():
    distances[(origin, node)] = math.sqrt((x0-x1)**2 + (y0-y1)**2)
```

Comment: Thank you! Do you know why my distance set is showing as empty after I change the code?

Comment: I don't know what you ran exactly. I had a small typo in `distances` (I wrote `distance` instead) but that should have thrown an error, so I assume you fixed that. If I fix the typo, `print(distances)` returns `{(1, 2): 7.0710678118654755, (1, 3): 14.142135623730951, (1, 1): 0.0}`